# Vuex: Unable to make page reactive after fetching data through axios on action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

What I'm trying to do is, on my page load I want to send a axios request to my server and then get the data and update my data. I'm loading a page called `homepage.vue` and there I have a component 'DashboardTop.vue'. I have vue extension enabled I get the required data but my mount or whatever it is not working. I'm missing something as a beginner.

I've tried doing `async await` the `axios` request.
here is my `store.js`:

```
state : {
        'token' : '',
        pendingOrderCount   : '', 
        processedOrderCount : '', 
        returnOrderCount    : '', 
    },  
    mutations : {
        updateOrderCounts(state, $counts){
            state.pendingOrderCount = $counts.pendingOrderCount;
            state.processedOrderCount = $counts.processedOrderCount;
            state.returnOrderCount = $counts.returnOrderCount;
        }
    },
    actions:{
        async sectionCounts(context){
            await axios.get('/dashboard/sectionCounts')
            .then(response => {
                context.commit('updateOrderCounts',response.data);            
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        },
    }
```

I'm `dispatching` the action `sectionCounts` on my `component` as:

```
        data(){
            return {
                pendingOrderCount   : this.$store.state.pendingOrderCount, 
                processedOrderCount : this.$store.state.processedOrderCount, 
                returnOrderCount    : this.$store.state.returnOrderCount,               
            }
        },  
        mounted(){
            this.$store.dispatch('sectionCounts');
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use computed property to update data after change. I recommend using *mapState* helper in these situations. See [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper)

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

...some code here...

computed: {
    ...mapState(['pendingOrderCount', 'returnOrderCount', ' processedOrderCount']),
},
```

Comment: thanks a bunch man.. but what is the difference between the mapstate and the mapgetters here? ..

Comment: Getters are like functions based on state. For example, you have numbers array in Vuex state, called numbers, and you will create a getter for positiveNumbers. Each time you mention positiveNumbers in code, the positiveNumbers function recalled again. But, state is like just your data. If you want to use reactive and changeable access to state in Vue components, you must use mapState helper. Because the data function is run once when the component created. For more information see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram and https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html.

Comment: Or just say data of the Vuex is called state and computer variables of the Vuex is called getters, not just like that, but similar.